# Parse URL with python

Tags: python, parsing

I would like to parse the following URL :
[Espacenet link](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults?DB=&ST=singleline&locale=fr_EP&query=ep2814089)

and I would like to obtain the URL corresponding to the text :

> 1. BATTERY PACK WITH A BUS BAR HAVING NOVEL STRUCTURE

I'm using python but I'm not really familiar with javascript.
How can I can get the job done ?

So far I've seen requests_html and I tried this code :

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

publication_number_to_scrape = "EP2814089"
url = "https://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults?ST=singleline&locale=fr_EP&submitted=true&DB=&query=ep2814089" + publication_number_to_scrape
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

# create an HTML Session object
session = HTMLSession()

# Use the object above to connect to needed webpage
resp = session.get(url, headers=headers)
print(resp.content)

# Run JavaScript code on webpage
html2 = resp.html.render()

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

and in the printed result, I've seen this part :

```
</li>
<li class="bendractive"><a accesskey="b" href="">Liste de résultats</a></li>
<li class="bendr"><a accesskey="c" class="ptn" href="/mydocumentslist?submitted=true&amp;locale=fr_EP" id="menuPnStar">Ma liste de brevets (<span id="menuPnCount"></span>)</a></li>
<li class="bendr"><a accesskey="d" href="/queryHistory?locale=fr_EP">Historique des requêtes</a></li>
<li class="spacer"></li>
<li class="bendl"><a accesskey="e" href="/settings?locale=fr_EP">Paramètres</a></li>
<li class="bendl last">
<a accesskey="f" href="/help?locale=fr_EP&amp;method=handleHelpTopic&amp;topic=index">Aide</a>
</li>
```

My goal is to obtain the following URL from the results :
[Wanted URL](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?II=0&ND=3&adjacent=true&locale=fr_EP&FT=D&date=20141217&CC=EP&NR=2814089A1&KC=A1#)

My final goal is to get a list with the string of each document appearing in that URL:

[image: The documents I need to parse in a string list]

I don't need the URLs of said documents, only the following list :

```
result = ['EP2814089 (A4)', 'EP2814089 (B1)', ....]
```

Comment: I finally use F12 with Chrome when loading the page and identified the response url I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium from Pyp https://pypi.org/project/selenium/

and get the id of what you're intersted or the xpath.

In your case :
`id=publicationId1` or `//a[@id='publicationId1']`
or `xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='|'])[5]/following::a[2]`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the job:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cookies = {
    'JSESSIONID': '9ULYIsd9+RmCkgzGPoLdCWMP.espacenet_levelx_prod_1',
    'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver.LOCALE': 'fr_EP',
    'menuCurrentSearch': '%2F%2Fworldwide.espacenet.com%2FsearchResults%3FDB%3D%26ST%3Dsingleline%26locale%3Dfr_EP%26query%3Dep2814089',
    'currentUrl': 'https%3A%2F%2Fworldwide.espacenet.com%2FsearchResults%3FDB%3D%26ST%3Dsingleline%26locale%3Dfr_EP%26query%3Dep2814089',
    'PGS': '10',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'tr,tr-TR;q=0.9',
}

params = (
    ('DB', ''),
    ('ST', 'singleline'),
    ('locale', 'fr_EP'),
    ('query', 'ep2814089'),
)

response = requests.get('https://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Thanks, that code also return a result. How can I extract the URL i am looking for from that result ? The url I'm looking for is the one I get when I'm clinking on  the texte "BATTERY PACK WITH A BUS BAR HAVING NOVEL STRUCTURE", ie : https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?II=0&ND=3&adjacent=true&locale=fr_EP&FT=D&date=20141217&CC=EP&NR=2814089A1&KC=A1#